# IE7 mode in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

How close does Internet Explorer 8 mimic IE7 when you set the browser mode to Internet Explorer 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to quantify, but here's a list of [specific differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be extremely close if not 100%.  Microsoft even supports allowing websites to force the compatibility mode to occur.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx